# I have a problem with the intersection code

Tags: c++

This function takes as input marathon runners and finishers, and is the code to find out who did not finish (c++ intersection problem).
However, I keep getting strange results.
Anyone know why this is happening? I need help.
condition :
The number of runners participating in the marathon is between 1 and 100,000.
The length of completion is one less than the length of participant.
The participant's name must consist of at least 1 and no more than 20 lowercase letters of the alphabet.
There may be other participants with the same name.

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

string solution(vector<string> participant, vector<string> completion) {
    map<string, int> playerMap;

    for (auto player : participant)++playerMap[player];
    for (auto player : completion)
    {
        --playerMap[player];
        if (playerMap[player] == 1)
            return player;
    }

}
```

Comment: Is there a chance that `playerMap[player]` is never 1? If so the code has undefined behavior.

Comment: You probably need to add a [mcve] which includes an `int main()` that produces the result you claim so people can easily test.

Comment: Before posting their first question on stackoverflow.com, everyone should take the [tour], read the [help], understand all the requirements for a [mre] and [ask] questions here. Not doing any of this results in a poor quality question almost every time. It then gets downvoted, closed, and then deleted. Repeated low-quality questions may result in a temporary ban from asking new questions.

Comment: @drescherjm: Unless a player participates twice, it's *guaranteed* the count is never `1` (because a matching participation and completion would decrement before the test and the count would always be `0`).

Comment: My general comment to all of this is:  Before you write a single line of code, you should have a plan on paper that takes care of all of the conditions.  Once you have that plan on paper, *then* you write the code that follows the plan.  When you do that, the solution becomes simple -- either the code you wrote doesn't follow your plan (then you debug the code to see why), or you determine that the plan was flawed and you start out with a new plan.  You don't simply write code, fiind out it doesn't work, and not know what to do.  Programmers don't work this way.

Answer (score 2):

Your code:

1. Only checks for a count of `1` when the player is seen to have finished, and only after decrementing. Thus, unless a player starts two or more times, that test can never hit.
2. It doesn't not specify a return value when no check hits, so undefined behavior occurs (you promise to return a string, and don't)

To fix, do what you're doing *without* a check, but then add a final loop to check for non-zero entries:

```
#include <vector>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

string solution(vector<string> participant, vector<string> completion) {
    map<string, int> playerMap;

    for (const auto& player : participant)++playerMap[player];  // Iterating by const ref to avoid needless copies
    for (const auto& player : completion) --playerMap[player];  // Simplify to just decrementing
    for (const auto& [player, count] : playerMap) {
        if (count > 0) return player;
    }
    return "";  // Or raise an exception, since returning an empty string is not hugely helpful
}
```

If we can assume a player can't start more than once, a simpler version of the code would *erase* the players that complete, so the work in the final loop is trivial:

```
string solution(vector<string> participant, vector<string> completion) {
    map<string, int> playerMap;

    for (const auto& player : participant)++playerMap[player];  // Iterating by const ref to avoid needless copies
    for (const auto& player : completion) playerMap.erase(player);  // Simplify to erasing

    for (const auto& [player, count] : playerMap) {
        return player; // No need for a test; anything remaining is an incomplete player
    }
    return "";  // Or raise an exception, since returning an empty string is not hugely helpful
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```cpp
for (auto player : completion)
{
    --playerMap[player];
    if (playerMap[player] == 1)
        return player;
}
```

Your problem is here. You are checking `playerMap[player] == 1` before taking into account every one who has complete the race. So, most likely, you are finding a wrong name by identifying it too soon.

You can fix this by only checking that condition after iterating the entire `completion` vector.

```cpp
for (auto player : completion) --playerMap[player];
for (auto [player, count] : playerMap)
    if (playerMap[player] == 1) return player;
```

You also need to add a return value at the end for the function to fall back on if it doesn't find a player who didn't complete the race.